# Showing $p\mid(a^2 +c^2)$ given $p\mid(a^2+b^2)$ and $p\mid(b^2+c^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I had no trouble showing this for $a^2-c^2$ but I'm running into a wall here.

A couple of routes that I took.

1)  $p\mid(a^2+b^2) \Rightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $a^2+b^2 =pk$

$p\mid(b^2+c^2) \Rightarrow \exists m\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $b^2+c^2 =pm$

But $a^2+c^2=pk+pm-2b^2$.  Then I have to show that $p\mid 2b^2$.  If I take the converse of the theorem that says if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, then $p\mid(ax+by)$ and take $x=a, b=y$.  But I don't think the converse is true, but I' also having trouble with that.

I've also tried to find a counter example but that also seems to be failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$17$ divides $4^2+1$ and $1+4^2$ but not $4^2+4^2$

Comment: Sometimes it's the easiest solutions that seem the hardest!  Thanks...(will check in 9 minutes...)

Comment: You are welcome!!

Comment: @Lalaloopsy It is is easy to *discover* such counterexamples if you *analyse* the consequences of the hypotheses - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ You know it implies $\,p\mid a^2-c^2.\,$ If, further, $\,p\mid a^2+c^2$ then adding and subtracting yields $\,p\mid 2a^2,2c^2,\,$ which is impossible if $\,p>2\,$ and $\,a,c\,$ are coprime, e.g. if $\,c = 1.$

Comment: Another great post.  I must say Bill, you are steadily helping to improve my understanding of this material.  It is clear I need to work on my analysis a bit, but you are steering me ahead.  Thank you.